# Django models with varied types of functionality

Tags: django, django-models, architecture

I have a use case where I want to capture various types of reminders for users (auto-generated by business logic) in a Django application.  Across all reminders, the attributes are the same (i.e. `owner`, `creator`, `creation_time`, `status`, `completion_time`) and they have the same interface (i.e. `render_message()`, `is_valid()`).  However, there are many types of reminders which should each have their own implementation details for these common functions.

Since the model attributes never change it seems like having a single Django model makes sense but then I question the best way to get from a model instance to the specific implementations of functions like `render_message()`.

I'm currently considering having a `ChoiceField` on the `Reminder` model called `type` which would map to the various reminder type classes and then have a helper function within `Reminder` that will instantiate the appropriate reminder type class based on `self.type` and call that for functionality like `render_message()`.

Am I missing a better way?  Not sure what this pattern is considered or where to look for similar examples of having a single Django model that's associated to a variety of implementations of the same interface.

Comment: Could you please give examples that illustrate how various implementations of `render_message` differ?

Comment: You can use `class Meta: abstract = True` or even `@abc.abstractmethod`, but I've never needed these Javaisms. If you're handling a Reminder somewhere that always has render_message(), just call it. If EatReminder has a different render_message, override it.

Comment: @AntoinePinsard each reminder is associated with a Project object.  One reminder type might be for overdue projects, so render_message would return `"<project_name> is over due by x days"`.  Another reminder type might be for projects that haven't had any update in a certain number of days that render_message implementation would return `"<project_name> hasn't been updated in x days"`.  In reality there are dozens of different scenarios.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use models to store the alerts, your requirement would be well catered for by [Django proxy models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/models/#proxy-models).

On a high-level, Django has three kinds of inheritances:

- [Abstract Base Class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes):

  > Base class table is not created, and all inherited models get all the fields of the base class
- [Multi-table inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance):

  > The second type of model inheritance supported by Django is when each
  >   model in the hierarchy is a model all by itself. Each model
  >   corresponds to its own database table and can be queried and created
  >   individually. The inheritance relationship introduces links between
  >   the child model and each of its parents (via an automatically-created
  >   OneToOneField).
- [Proxy Models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/models/#proxy-models)

  > When using multi-table inheritance, a new database table is created
  >   for each subclass of a model. This is usually the desired behavior,
  >   since the subclass needs a place to store any additional data fields
  >   that are not present on the base class. Sometimes, however, you only
  >   want to change the Python behavior of a model – perhaps to change the
  >   default manager, or add a new method.
  >
  > This is what proxy model inheritance is for: creating a proxy for the
  >   original model. You can create, delete and update instances of the
  >   proxy model and all the data will be saved as if you were using the
  >   original (non-proxied) model. The difference is that you can change
  >   things like the default model ordering or the default manager in the
  >   proxy, without having to alter the original.

Example:

```
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class MyPerson(Person):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True

    def do_something(self):
        # ...
        pass

class AlienPerson(Person):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True

    def do_something(self):
        pass
```

Cool thing is, it helps you in creating different admin interfaces even though the objects are stored in the same table :) [reference](http://benlopatin.com/using-django-proxy-models/)

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of proxy models and they almost seem like what I want.  The problem is, I want to be able to iterate through the list of all Reminders for a particular user and be able to call the different `render_message` implementations for each.  But I don't think I could do that with proxy models since I'd have to retrieve a collection of Reminder objects and then would have no way to get from there to different proxy implementations.  I should also mention it is beneficial from an analytics perspective to know across all reminders how many of each type there are.

Comment: @user857159 the discussion [here](http://blog.headspin.com/?p=474) might interest you. Basically you can create an object of the parent class, filter the objects and then call the methods. I would also suggest looking at the comments. Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You can store the custom part of the logic into the database.

```
class Reminder:

    message_template = forms.TextField()

    def render_message(self):
        render_message_dict = self.get_render_message_dict()
        return self.message_template.format(**render_message_dict)

    def get_render_message_dict(self):
        return {
            'project_name': self.project_name,
            'due_for_days': (date.today() - self.due_date).days,
            'updated_for_days': (date.today() - self.last_updated.date()).days,
        }
```

So you set:

```
reminder_a.message_template = '{project_name} is over due by {due_for_days} days'
reminder_b.message_template = '{project_name} hasn't been updated in {updated_for_days} days'
```

If you have a given set of message templates, you could also use a choice field instead:

```
class Reminder:

    MESSAGE_TEMPLATE_CHOICES = [
        (1, _("{project_name} is over due by {due_for_days} days")),
        (2, _("{project_name} hasn't been updated in {updated_for_days} days")),
    ]

    message_template = forms.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
        choices=MESSAGE_TEMPLATE_CHOICES)

    def render_message(self):
        render_message_dict = self.get_render_message_dict()
        return self.message_template.format(**render_message_dict)

    def get_render_message_dict(self):
        return {
            'project_name': self.project_name,
            'due_for_days': (date.today() - self.due_date).days,
            'updated_for_days': (date.today() - self.last_updated.date()).days,
        }
```

Which also enables marking message templates as translatable.